# Forgot virtualenv name - how to find the name of the virtual env?

Tags: virtualenv

I set up a flask site with uwsgi/nginx a while back, and set up a virtualenv.. I've forgotten the name of the venv I set up, and I can't find any way to list the virtualenv in a current dir.

How do I find out the name of my virtualenv?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it’s definitely in the current directory, try `ls */bin/python`. Otherwise, `ls **/python`, or `find . -name python`. You can, of course, just make a new one, too.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the nooby question - I did try searching SO and google beforehand but neither came up with a clear answer. find .-name python provided me with the venv name.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a conda virtualenv you can do the following:
`conda info --envs`
Now, Select your virtual environment and perform this:
`conda activate <your_env>`