# I can't remember the name of the virtual environment - how can I see a list of all virtual environments?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I installed a virtual environment as per: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

I stopped working on the project for a few days and can't remember the name of the environment. How can I find out the name? I've done some searchign and came across this exact question here:

[Forgot virtualenv name - how to find the name of the virtual env?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358474/forgot-virtualenv-name-how-to-find-the-name-of-the-virtual-env)

When I try the suggestions the terminal just says the command doesn't exist.

Comment: If you said you followed those instructions, do you happen to have a `venv` folder in the same directory as your code?

Comment: A virtualenv is just a directory in your file system. Usually you can find it by poking around the directories you normally use for such things. Otherwise, look for one of the env files such as `activate_this.py`

Comment: I managed to find the name of it (I found a screenshot of my terminal) but when I type "workon envname" I still get: -bash: workon: command not found

Comment: workon isn't a command, then. You need to do `source /path/to/venv/bin/activate`

Comment: Use virtualenvwrapper, and forget about those headaches. You would just use `lsvirtualenv` then.

Comment: `workon` is, in fact, a `virtualenvwrapper` command, and without arguments it will give you a list of the installed virtualenvs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using conda try this at the command prompt:

conda env list

This should give you a summary of all accessible environment which you have created.

Comment: Create environment:  conda create -n <name of your env> python=3.7
Activation of environment: conda activate <name of your env>.

Answer (score 0):

Using the terminal `cd` here `/Users/${USER}/Library/Jupyter/kernels` and then do an `ls` to see all your names.

got this answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976367/how-do-i-delete-refresh-available-kernels-for-ipython-jupyter-notebook-v4-0)

Answer (score 0):

From my bash terminal, I type `ls` and it lists all of my directories from there, including my virtual environments. If you do not see your virtual environments listed, try changing directory into the folder that it is contained in.

Answer (score 0):

To find the lost Django virtual Environments.
in the terminal type the command : lsvirtualenv
or in Windows Operating System you are able to see it in File Explorer

C:\Users<User Name>\Envs\

Answer (score 0):

I typically do this:

> ```
> conda info --envs
> ```