# Django virtualenv name forgotten

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have created and worked on a Django application (Simple website with user registration and login) without ever closing the virtualenv i was working on.
Now that some time went through I can't remember the name of the virtualenv I was working on and so I can't activate it. How can I find the name of the virtualenv?

The name of the directory of my django app is "uniweb" and is on the desktop of my computer. I haven't yet put it on Github.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forgot virtualenv name - how to find the name of the virtual env?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358474/forgot-virtualenv-name-how-to-find-the-name-of-the-virtual-env)

Comment: @lacopo? Are u using `virtualenv` or `virtualenv-wrapper`? which OS are you using, Linux? `virtualenv` creates the environment  in the directory you executed the command, you will find a directory with a name of the environment. `mkvirtualenv` creates the environment in a directory that is configured in `~/.bashrc`, usually `~/.virtualenvs`

Comment: @toto_tico thank you very much for your help, at the end I decided to create a new virtualenv from top to bottom and import in there my Django app. Thank you very much indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

though this problem can be solved by making another environment and importing project there. it can also be solved 

here is how i solved the same problem.
if you got the same name. it is just simple as you have to use `workon` on command promt inside the directory you have created the django project and it shows the list of all virtual environments you have created there, so you can remember the name and use your virtual environment